# Jersey: how to implement JPA encryption with dynamic keys

Tags: hibernate, jersey, jasypt

I am building a REST aplication based on Jersey 2 and Hibernate 4.3. Some entity attributes should be stored in encrypted form. I am currently using [Jasypt](http://jasypt.org/hibernate.html) for this purpose. For example, I have

```
@TypeDef(
   name = "encryptedString", 
   typeClass = EncryptedStringType.class, 
   parameters = {
      @Parameter(name = "encryptorRegisteredName",
                 value = "myHibernateStringEncryptor")
   }
)

@Entity
public class User
{
   ...
   @Type( type = "encryptedString" )
   private String password_;
   ...
}
```

"myHibernateStringEncryptor" is just a `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` which is created at startup.

This works fine as long as my encryptor always uses the same key. However, I have to use dynamic keys based on the REST request context (basically, each user's data must be encrypted with a different key).

**How can I do this while still having transparent encrytion?** The encryption key is available for injection in request scope, and I am prepared to write my own `UserType`. But the `UserType` instance is static so I cannot simply inject the key.

Comment: Could the encryption key be created on request? That way, you could have a filter where you get/create your encryption key. You can store it in a ThreadLocal for the duration of the request (clear in a response filter) and that way have it available for the time of the request. Your decrypt/encrpyt class can than just do MyClass.ThreadLocal.get()

Comment: That would be possible. But I'd rather have a solution that does not depend on `ThreadLocal` because my application logic can be executed by different threads (e.g., I might use Hystrix to wrap database accesses).

Comment: How about using a custom MessageBodyWriter? It will be called after you executed all your logic, so you can use a custom writer to encrypt the data before it goes out?